# How do I make XmlSerialiser not start with <?xml ?>?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, ofx

The file format I'm working with (OFX) is XML-like and contains a bunch of plain-text stuff before the XML-like bit begins. It doesn't like having  between the plain-text and XML parts though, so I'm wondering if there's a way to get XmlSerialiser to ignore that. I know I could go through the file and wipe out that line but it would be simpler and cleaner to not write it in the first place! Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not too tough, you just have to serialize to an explicitly declared XmlWriter and set the options on that writer before you serialize.

```
public static string SerializeExplicit(SomeObject obj)
{    
    XmlWriterSettings settings;
    settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

    XmlSerializerNamespaces ns;
    ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add("", "");


    XmlSerializer serializer;
    serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeObject));

    //Or, you can pass a stream in to this function and serialize to it.
    // or a file, or whatever - this just returns the string for demo purposes.
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    using(var xwriter = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings))
    {

        serializer.Serialize(xwriter, obj, ns);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You'll have to manipulate the XML writer object you use when calling the [`Serialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.serialize.aspx) method. Its `Settings` property has a [`OmitXmlDeclaration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.omitxmldeclaration.aspx) property, which you'll want to set to true. You'll also need to set the `ConformanceLevel` property, otherwise the XmlWriter will ignore the `OmitXmlDeclaration` property.

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(/*whatever stream you need*/,settings);
serializer.Serialize(writer,objectToSerialize);
writer.close();
```

Comment: Apologies; turns out that the ConformanceLevel part makes serializer.Serialize throw an exception. So I've yanked that 'accept' out from under you! :) You still get an upvote, of course, and a 'thank you'!